# Checking whether the autocomplete is empty

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using the jquery ui. I am currently using the autocomplete widget. Basically I have a button and want to know if the user has entered anything in that autocomplete box. If not, then make a string equal to null else get the test and assign it to a var.

This is code:

```
$(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "The Alps",
  "Europe",
  "Africa",
  "The Caribbean",
  "Indian Ocean",
  "North and Central America",
  "South America",
  "Asia"
];
$( "#destination" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
});

$('#destination').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
 var ii = ui.item.value;
 alert(ii);
    if(ii == "" || ii == null || ii == undefined){

    }else{
     destination(ii);
    }
  });

function destination(nameOfResort){
        destination = nameOfResort;
        alert("name " + destination);
    }
```

As you can see in the if statement, if the autocomplete box is empty, then it shouldn't do anything but when the alert  is called, it displays the following in a pop up box:

```
name  function destination(nameOfResort){
            destination = nameOfResort;
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be ui.val(). Also consider testing for undefined/null first and then destination.trim().length == 0 and avoiding empty blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what is the exact issue but if your code is not working then just try to put `autocompleteselect` inside `$(function()`

```
$(function() {
        var availableTags = [
          "The Alps",
          "Europe",
          "Africa",
          "The Caribbean",
          "Indian Ocean",
          "North and Central America",
          "South America",
          "Asia"
        ];
        $( "#destination" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags

        });
        $('#destination').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
            var ii = ui.item.value;
            alert(ii);
            if(ii == "" || ii == null || ii == undefined){

            }else{
                destination(ii);
            }
         });
    });
```